# Get Mac-Address in Single-User Mode in Mac OS X 10.8?

Tags: mac, command-line, macbook-pro, mac-address

I was wondering if there is a way to get all the mac addresses of my network interfaces in single-user mode in OS X 10.8. I've tried ifconfig, but since single-user mode doesn't turn on networking, I doesn't display much useful information.

Any clue on how I can get this info while in single-user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In single user mode:

```
# mount -uw /
# launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.configd.plist
```

You can use ifconfig after that to see the network interface hardware addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The `system_profiler` command *might* provide this information. I'm not sure whether it reports hardware info without active interfaces.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't give me any Mac Addresses. Good suggestion though.